# Classic ASP hacer una tarea cada 5 min solo 3 veces

Tags: asp, datetime, session, timer

Buenos días, necesito en classic asp hacer una script que usando las variables de sesion, haga cuando una determinada variable este a true, 3 veces una accion y entre cada una de las veces debe pasar 5 minutos, llevo dias pensando en como hacerlo sin que me salga, se agradecería cualquier ayuda.

```
Session("TimesToAlert")=0

if Session("TimesToAlert")<3 then 

    response.write "Hi !"

end if

if alert then
   Session("TimesToAlert")=Session("TimesToAlert")+1

end if
```

Comment: Podrías crear un servicio aparte de tu código ASP e invocarlo cuando tus condiciones se cumplan desde el ASP. Teniendo en ese servicio un Timer que se realice lo que quieras cada 5 minutos.

Comment: Te aconsejaría crear un método async, haces que cada 5 minutos se ejecute y solo lo haga tres veces